# Downloading all PDF files from a website

Tags: c#, pdf

I need to make a windows desktop application in c# that downloads all the PDFs from a website. I have the link to the website but the problem i am facing is that the PDFs are not in a specific folder on the website but are scattered all over.

The thing i need is help at finding all those links so i can download them or any other advices that could help me with my problem.

Thanks to all help in advanced.

Comment: So you want to write a spider?

Comment: I am sure there are many free solutions available that could do it.

Comment: yes I think I need a spider but i didn't know what to search for. Now i have googled for spiders and i realy need something like that.

Comment: While it would be a loooong way to your aim, if you really want to understand how to do that well look at [this free online course](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs101). At least for the crawler part.

Answer (score 1):

1. Scrape through all the pages
2. Find all the "*.pdf" URLs
3. Reconstruct them and simply download :)

Please be more specific are you trying to get all the PDFs from the html page or from the whole domain ?

Comment: I need to find all the pdfs from the whole domain.

Comment: You can use google! Google for "*.pdf inurl:website" and it should give you a list of all indexed accessible PDF files. Does that help ?

Comment: I thought about that but I wanted to find a more programmable solution

Comment: Sorry. Search for "-filetype:pdf inurl:domain" . Read here http://www.google.com/help/faq_filetypes.html

Comment: I would stick to searching for "*.pdf" in the page as well as links to other HTML/HTM/ASP/ASPX/PHP pages in the document and then would loop through all the found pages and PDF links. Of course reconstructing PDF URL could cause some problem

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is known as [Web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), there are some libraries which can make your task easy one of them is [IronWebScraper](https://ironsoftware.com/) but its paid one.

An extensive list of NuGet packages is available [here](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/scraping) which can be used for web scraping purpose.